# How to click button using Mechanize in perl?

Tags: html, perl, button, mechanize

```
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenConsolidateFiles" value="0">
<button type="button" style="width:220px;" onClick="javascript:viewFullTextOfTreaty()" value="full" name="full" id="full">View Full Text of Treaty</button>
<button type="button" style="display:none;" onClick="javascript:viewFullText()" value="" id="sim">View Other Relevant Treaty Information</button>
<button type="button" style="display:none;" onClick="javascript:viewConsolidated()" value="consol" name="consol" id="consol">View Consolidated Version of Treaty</button>
```

I have the above `HTML`.  I want to click the button named `full` using `Mechanize` in `perl`.  How can I do this?

I have tried `$mech->click("full")` and `$mech->click_button(name => 'full')` and `$mech->click_button(value => 'full')` but none have worked. They all say there is "no clickable input with name full".

Answer (score 0):

I have no problems downloading your PDF:

```
my $url =
"http://ec.europa.eu/world/agreements/downloadFile.do?fullText=yes&treatyTransId=520";
{
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    $mech->get($url);

    my ($filename) = $mech->{res}->{_headers}->{"content-disposition"} =~ m{filename=([^"]+)};
    $mech->save_content($filename);
};
```

**UPDATE**

```
my $url =
  "http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($url);
$mech->save_content("1.htm");

#HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" URL
my ($tmp_url) = $mech->content() =~ m{URL=([^"]+)};
$mech->get( "http://daccess-ods.un.org" . $tmp_url );
$mech->save_content("2.htm");

my ($pdf_url) = $mech->content() =~ m{URL=([^"]+)};
my ($cookie_url) = $mech->content() =~ m{src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)};

#First we need to get cookies
$mech->get($cookie_url);

#Next we can load PDF file
$mech->get($pdf_url);
$mech->save_content("Result.pdf");
```

***Important note:***
**Parsing HTML with regular expressions is really bad idea** (my favorite module is HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML)

Comment: OK, try this one: http://daccess-ods.un.org/access.nsf/Get?Open&DS=A/HRC/WGAD/2015/28&Lang=E